# Quicktime default window position

Tags: macos, default-settings, quicktime

I use Quicktime a lot to record audio, screen recordings, and movie recordings. But each time I open the app the window position is in the upper left corner, regardless of where I positioned it in the last use.

Can this window position setting be controlled? Many other settings retain the "last used values" (such as whether to use the microphone, which input sources, ...).

Another (less) annoying thing is that a finder window initially appears the first time I open the app -- I just hit cancel every time and then reposition the window. Software should be smarter than that.

Note: I'm not sure where to ask this question. I asked this on Stack Overflow with no response, so I'm not sure it's programming related enough so I came here.